# Identifying a returned ajax object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: rAction,
    data: rData,
    success: function(msg){

        if(msg.indexOf('ERROR:')>1){

        }

        if(msg.indexOf('ERROR:')==-1){
                        }
         })
```

When it's an error, it returns the msg which contains html and it works fine... but when there is NO error, I am getting an error in the console that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'
```

I can't seem to run an if statement on that successful msg and it's messing me up! what type of object is that?

How can I check a success vs an error page?

Comment: What does your response object look like if it's not an error?

Comment: objects don't have an indexOf method, only strings and arrays(in newer browsers) do !

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the type of `msg` when it comes back successfully? My guess would be that it's returning a JSON string which is getting automatically converted into an object -- which would _not_ have an `indexOf` method.

Comment: @founddrama, how would i pull that off?

Comment: Looks like you've accepted an answer down there already, but you'd want to use the `typeof` operator to check the type; it will return a string to indicate the type of the object you're inspecting. And/but be aware that it can be quirky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(typeof(msg) == "string"){
   //do your stuff here
}
```